# What is the appropriate lifecycle stage to do redirects in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to render a component based on an external condition, else redirect elsewhere in the app.

Ideally this redirection would be decided before the component, but in some cases I feel like I need to do this in the component. For example, in ReactRouter, the router might look like this:

```
<Router>
    <Route path='/' component={LoadingPage} />
    <Route path='/Home' component={HomePage} />
    <Route path='/Login' component={LoginPage} />
</Router>
```

and the logic / sudocode for the LoadingPage will go something like this:

```
if (stillLoading) {
    render
} else if (loggedIn) {
    redirectToHome
} else {
    redirectToLogin
}
```

It gets complicated, because sometimes the app is already loaded before the component is requested.

What lifecycle stage is the most appropriate place to put this redirection logic?

- Render / a method called from Render? (seems odd)
- ComponentDidMount + Make an event listener for later?
- GetInitialState? (but should not have side-effects?)
- ComponentWillMount?
- Other?

Comment: check out `onEnter` in the React Router docs, and the auth-flow example in the repo

Comment: @knowbody - awesome! That's exactly what I'm looking for. So the answer was indeed the null - do the redirection before the component is even started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar app, and I apply the flux pattern. I create a `loginStore` to save the login status, and other pages watch it. I use [higher order component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750) to watch the store changes, so the loading status is passed into other components through `props`. Then I do the page transition in `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`.

If you don't apply flux pattern, I think you have to decide how to know the external condition first. For example, put the logic in `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` if the external condition comes from `props`.

Don't put the redirection logic in render which should be `pure`. Every time when you invoke the `render` method, it only returns the description of your `DOM` instead of transition your page.

`ComponentWillMount` also doesn't work. It's only invoked once and may be called before you login. `GetInitialState` also has this problem, and it should only provide the initial state of your component.

Comment: What do you suggest if my props are coming from my Redux state? And I want to check if the `this.props.match.params.lockId` has a corresponding `lock._id`. If not I want to redirect back to `/`.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is now legacy and considered unsafe. It's being replaced with `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`, so should be avoided, as people misused those methods.

Comment: @zmechanic thank you. I've already updated the answer.

Comment: But it does not give an answer to the question now

Answer (score 1):

I do redirect in `componentDidMount` and have no issues with this, as I need redirects only during initial page load. I support other people in thinking that `render` should remain pure, and always return valid DOM. If I know that I'll need to redirect, I just do `return null;` from `render`.

Comment: Before componentDidMount is fired - you will have an extra rerendering. Except extra render, it also can lead to bugs.

Comment: @andrfas That's why I explicitly stated that I do `return null;` from `render`. Yes, React will call `render`, but it does nothing, effectively. What approach you think is more appropriate, then?